# Why is my precision web layout imprecise?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having a problem modifying HTML with Javascript.  An example can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/02mwyvyo/

My goal is to move a specific element down the page.  I am trying to do this by inserting a spacer `div` before the target element.  The spacer `div`'s style attributes are `style="display: inline-block; width=1px; height=100px;"`.

Here is the code I am using:

```
function describeDOMRect(rect) {
  return "{ top: " + rect.top + ", left: " + rect.left + ", bottom: " + rect.bottom + ", right: " + rect.right + " }"
}

function addVerticalSpacer() {
  var div = document.getElementsByClassName("target-div")[0]
  var bounds = div.getBoundingClientRect()

  console.log("old bounds: " + describeDOMRect(bounds))

  var spacerHeight = 100
  var newTop = bounds.top + spacerHeight
  var spacer = document.createElement("div")

  spacer.className = "spacer"
  spacer.setAttribute("style", "display: inline-block; width: 1px; height: " + spacerHeight + "px;")

  div.parentNode.insertBefore(spacer, div)

  bounds = div.getBoundingClientRect()

  console.log("new bounds: " + describeDOMRect(bounds))
}
```

And here are the CSS properties applied to `div`:

```
div {
  border: none;
  border-width: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

When I run the code above, this is what I see in the console:

```
old bounds: { top: 26, left: 8, bottom: 26, right: 729 }
new bounds: { top: 112, left: 8, bottom: 112, right: 729 }
```

Notice the old top position is 26, so I expect the new top to be 126, but it is 112.

Why is this happening?  What can I do to correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually inserting the spacer `div` between *Some text* and *Some more text*. Since it is an `inline-block` it is appended at the end of the first line.

[image]

Comment: Ah. How can I make it break so it starts after the text?

Comment: Use `display: block` instead of `inline-block`. Where exactly do you intend to insert visual space?

Comment: Please add that to your answer and I'll accept it.  You are my hero.

Comment: Honestly I don't care if you accept it. It's all here.

Comment: So it is.  Thank you.